# laravel 5.2 custom login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I try to create custom login page but I got an error

**`Undefined index: password`**

my controller code

```
$this->validate($Request, [
        'Email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
        ]);
         $email    = $Request['Email'];
         $password     =  md5($Request['password']);
         $login    = new login();
         $login    = login::where('Email', $email);
         if(empty($password))
         {
            return('404');
         }
         if(Auth::attempt(['Email' => $Request->input('Email'), 'Password' =>$password]))
         {
            return ('ok');
         }
         return ('no');
```

any one help my to create custom login

**this is my new code**

but again i gor undefined::passsword

```
public function logincheck(Request $request)
    {
         $this->validate($request, [
        'Email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
        ]);
         $email    = $request->Email;
         $password     =  md5($request->get('password'));
         if(Auth::attempt(['Email' => $request->get('Email'), 'Password' =>md5($request->get('password'))]))
         {
            return ('ok');
         }
         return ('no');
    }
```

Comment: show your form. the names of your input fields should match exactly. this is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Your error comes from

```
$Request['password']
```

You are treating Request as an array. It's an object. You do

```
public funciton login(Request $request)
{
    $password = $request->password;
    //or use the global helper 
    $password = request('password');


    //Attempt login 
    if(Auth::attempt(['Email' => $request->get('Email'), 'Password' =>$password]))
    {
        return ('ok');
    }
}
```

Also if you follow Laravel tutorial properly, you don't need `md5` to hash password. `Auth::attemp()` will hash it for you

Comment: Update your code please, I want to see where the error comes from.

Comment: public function logincheck(Request $request)
    {
      $this->validate($request, [
        'Email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
     ]);
      $email    = $request->Email;
      $password     =  md5($request->get('password'));
      if(Auth::attempt(['Email' => $request->get('Email'), 'Password' =>md5($request->get('password'))]))
      {
       return ('ok');
      }
      return ('no');
    }

Comment: you need to debug your code. Just before `Auth::attemp()` add `return $request->all();` and see what it gives you, please.

Comment: i got this output {"Email":"admin@admin.com","password":"admin","_token":"vX40APWTtoDNbBwA0izwmSkhXvQIryOoZQLwrDMK"}

Comment: ok. We keep debugging my friend. now in the Auth::attempt(), manullay put values like `Auth::attempt(['email' => 'admin@admin.com', 'password' => 'admin']);`. With manual input, let's see if it works.

Comment: sorry bro again i got an same error **ErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 116:
Undefined index: password **

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138202/discussion-between-eddythedove-and-saran).